# How do I code my Add-on so that Firefox knows where to check for updates?

Tags: firefox-addon, auto-update, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an Add-on and I am having trouble finding documentation that explains how to let Firefox know where to look for updates.  If I post an .xpi on my website and the user downloads and installs that .xpi, does Firefox know to check that URL for changes? or do I have to put something in package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the online builder or the SDK command-line tool? You can only specify the update url using the cfx tool:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx

When building your add-on, you would run `cfx xpi` with the following arguments:

```
cfx xpi --update-link https://example.com/addon/latest
          --update-url https://example.com/addon/update_rdf
```

If you have already built your add-on using builder, a hackier option would be to download the xpi, unzip it, manually edit install.rdf and then re-zip it. See MDN for documentation on install.rdf syntax:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests

Comment: Also important: [update.rdf format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Versioning%2C_Update_and_Compatibility#Update_RDF_Format). And: the default (when no update URL is specified) is to look for updates on addons.mozilla.org. So add-ons hosted there get updates "for free".

Comment: Is the https protocol required?

Comment: I used this technique, but it always complains that the resulting .xpi is incompatible with 12.0, when I remove the --update-link and --update-url arguments, the .xpi works, am I missing something?

Comment: Try updating the maxVersion field in install.rdf to '14.0a1'. The value '12.0a1' provided in install.rdf with SD 1.6.1 is incorrect.

Comment: @RobertLouisMurphy Yes, the HTTPS protocol is required.

Comment: @RobertLouisMurphy There is [an alternative for http](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#updateKey)